# AWS S3 Geo location Redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, geolocation, detection

So I have a domain: example.com that domain translates to an s3 bucket in AWS example.com/index.html.

Although, what I want to do is if someone requests my domain from let say Japan instead of it going to 
example.com/index.html I want the traffic redirected to example.com/jp/index.html.
and English speaking countries get redirected to example.com/en/index.html.

My goal is to remove the root index.html and have my sub directories handle the languages.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: are you using aws cloudfront / willing to use cloudfront? this will improve your sites performance with edge capability and you can build in origin + header logic

Comment: Will the destination pages contain the same content, or are you wanting to present pages that contain different languages as their content? Also, is your entire site on Amazon S3 (with no compute component)?

Comment: So the design of the website changes depending on language. which is why it needs it own index.html instead of just using js and populating fields. Yes the entire site resides in S3.